# Why the `contain` Image does not fill the container in React Native?

Tags: flexbox, react-native

When I apply a network image, like

```
<View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:"black"}}>
    <Image resizeMode="contain" 
     source={{uri : "http://a-url-of-600x400-image.jpg"}} 
     style={{flex:1}}/>
</View>
```

There seems to be no way to fill the container by `contain` mode. And what I actually get is as,
[image]

the only way to fill the container is to use a much large image, e.g. 1000x800.

Is there any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It should be  `<Image resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.contain}>`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on Android that should be fixed with this pull request: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/5738